# How to package a Python Game made in Python using Pygame?

Tags: python, module, pygame, package, release

So recently I made a game in python pygame and when I want to try it on a different computer it cant work because I don't have pygame as a package there, so my question is what do I do when I want to give my game to a friend without him having to get all the packages/modules I used to code it?

Comment: You probably want to look into making an executable from your game. There are plenty of tools such as [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) and [cx_Freeze](https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). Note some only work with certain versions of Python. Also note that you may need to download some extra libraries if you're compiling it on a windows platform. If all else fails, perhaps look into making a sort-of "setup" scrip which users of your game can use to install your dependencies(Python obviously, Pygame, etc...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to compile it into an executable. You can use a popular program like [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial) to convert your project into an executable that can be used on any windows platform. Just make sure you are using the right version of python.